# How do I pass a lambda from Java to a Kotlin method?

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda

Can I call this Kotlin method from Java?

`fun foo(() -> Unit)`

If so, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call this but need to be careful of the return types. If your Kotlin function returns a `Unit`, Java will either need to return `Unit` or `null`, because `void` is not quite the same as `Unit`.

My example that worked:

```
foo(() -> {
    System.out.println("Hi");
    return null;
});
```

Or, if you want to be really explicit about `Unit`...

```
foo(() -> {
    System.out.println("Hi");
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure about that `null`? Won't the intrinstics say "expected non-null but received null"?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I was worried about that, but I ran it and nothing complained.

Answer (score 10):

You need to create instance of `Function0`:

```
foo(new Function0<Unit>() {
    @Override
    public Unit invoke() {
        // Here should be a code you need
        return null;
    }
});
```

or if you use Java 8 it can be simplified

```
foo(() -> {
    // Here should be a code you need
    return null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with Andrew's Answer, There is a better way to approach

1. You need to see generated Kotlin Bytecode -> Decompile it

In your case it looks something like this:

```
   public static final void foo(@NotNull Function0 acceptLambda) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(acceptLambda, "acceptLambda");
   }
```

now you know in order to call this function form Java you need to create instance of Function0 something like this

```
foo(new Function0<Unit>() {
    @Override
    public Unit invoke() {
        // Your Code
        return null;
    }
});
```